# Pythonic way to update multiple class variables in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to update class variables with similar names in a loop:

I have the following code:

```
class Table:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    acc_counter = 0
    acc0 = 0
    acc1 = 0
    acc2 = 0
    acc3 = 0
    acc4 = 0
```

I could update each value manually:

```
Table.acc0 = 0
Table.acc1 = 1
Table.acc2 = 2
Table.acc3 = 3
Table.acc4 = 4
```

However, I'm wondering if I could do it in a loop, something like that:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(getattr(Table, f"acc{i}"))
    #getattr(Table, f"acc{i}") = i
```

If the last line of the code is uncommented it returns: "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"

Comment: Have a look at `setattr`. But if you need to do such  things, it might be a sign that your separate attributes should rather be part of a list or dict.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thank you very much!

Comment: @Gооd_Mаn, what is the intention and responsibility of your `Table` class. Does it hold only static attributes without any declared behaviour?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, привет, it will be used for MSSQL.

Comment: @Gооd_Mаn, 2nd question was: *Does it hold only static attributes without any declared behaviour?* Are you using sqlalchemy for that?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, 
No, not only static, it is just a simplified sample code. 
yes, I'm using the sqlalchemy.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest did you have something in mind, that potentially could help me?

Comment: @Gооd_Mаn, you've already accepted the answer, here on SO that means that you got the needed help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `setattr` function:

```
for i in range(5):
    setattr(Table, f"acc{i}", i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `setattr` to set the object's attribute value

```
for i in range(5):
    print(getattr(Table, f"acc{i}"))
    setattr(Table, f"acc{i}", i)
```